# If a web server only has a 2048-bit RSA key, can a FREAK based attack still happen?

Tags: openssl, known-vulnerabilities

I think I'm missing something with the FREAK SSL vulnerability. I understand that the MITM server requests the RSA EXPORT ciphersuite which is limited to a 512-bit key (which in turn is feasible to factor the primes using 8 hours of cloud computing). But what if the server only has a single 2048-bit RSA Private key on the server? Wouldn't that make it protected from the attack?

Answer (score 3):

The RSA "export" cipher suites can work a bit like ephemeral Diffie-Hellman: if the server's "permanent" key is longer than 512 bits, then the server is supposed to generate a new one (dynamically) of length 512 bits, and send it over the wire as a `ServerKeyExchange` message, *signed* with its permanent private key. See [section 7.4.3 of RFC 2246](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2246#section-7.4.3). The private key you see (your 2048-bit key), the one that is stored in a file or some sort of certificate store on the server, is then used only for signatures; actual key exchange (encryption of the random pre-master secret with a RSA public key) happens with the temporary RSA key that the server generated.

Note that while the server *may* generate a new 512-bit RSA key pair for each connecting client, it will usually not do so because of the involved CPU cost (it is possible to generate RSA-512 key pairs quite quickly on modern hardware, but the support code for export cipher suites is more than 15 years old and is unlikely to have been optimized over the years). Therefore, many servers that still support RSA export cipher suites will generate a new RSA-512 key pair upon start, and then use it for all incoming clients that want to use such an export cipher suite. The so-called FREAK attack is made somehow practical because of that reuse: it allows the attacker to spend the 8-hour breaking effort *before* engaging in an actual Man-in-the-Middle (because the victim, a random Web user, is unlikely to wait for 8 hours that his SSL handshake completes).

Comment: Hi @Thomas, thanks for pointing me to that section of the RFC. So just to re-hash that, if the client (or the MITM server) requests the RSA Export cipher suite, the server will generate a dynamic 512-bit RSA key. Will this 512-bit RSA key be in the format of "BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY" and will it be unprotected without a pass phrase? I'm trying to understand how INRIA were able to spoof the NSA's certificate: http://goo.gl/9Agf6C, as in how did they use the factored 512-bit private key?